# Renaming/refactoring a View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I used this tutorial to rename a view controller
http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/14/how-to-rename-a-class-using-refactoring-in-xcode-4/

Basically just switch to Symbol Navigator view click on the view controller and then Edit > Refactor > Rename

Worked great!

However, when I go to symbol navigator now, my newly named view controller doesn't show there anymore?

Why did it disappear?  What if I want to rename it again?

Thanks!

Comment: Just tried.. still now showing in Symbols

Comment: In my case, the 'rename' option is greyed out in symbol view. Is there another way to rename classes without getting lots of errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use File >> Add files to "project name" and select your viewcontroller file. If your program doesn't have the files explicitly in its directory of files to load, it tends to ignore them.